# iPad numeric keyboard

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I've been trying to get a numeric keypad on the iPad, but when I set a numeric pad on a TextField, I get a normal keyboard with numbers and ponctuation. But I found out several bugs on the simulator, I don't really know if this is another.

Is there a standard keypad on the iPad?

Comment: Can you put up an example page we can browse to?

Comment: Never mind, tested it on an iPad - using <input type="number" /> doesn't trigger a Numerical keyboard.

Comment: I made a tutorial of one way to achieve a numeric keyboard (basically custom made) on iPad. Here: http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-make-custom-ios-number-keyboard.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The iPad's "number' keyboard is exactly what you're seeing. There is no "iPhone identical" number only pad. I've worked around this by just using UIButtons and custom code in my app, [Nippon](http://itunes.com/apps/nippon). I've also created a background foe the button. It's sized for a modal view controller with the `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` style.

Here are the images, in case you want to use them:

[image: Wide Key for iPad]
[image: Wide Pressed Key for iPad]

As for code, you force the UITextField to hide the keyboard and then you manually update the value when the button is pressed.

Comment: can you share a code snippet about that here ? we really need such important thing. thank you in advance.