# Setting keyboard type doesn't affect the keyboard. What's wrong?

Tags: objective-c, ios, types, keyboard, uitextfield

Changing the keyboard type of my uitextfield doesn't affect which keys appear on the ipad simulator. I have no clue why it's not working.

attributes

[image]

keyboard

[image]

Comment: What results were you expecting exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working correctly, there is no iPhone equivalent on the iPad.  See this post:

[iPad numeric keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625709/ipad-numeric-keyboard)